# Generating a function via for-loop for the Jacobian matrix in R

Tags: r, function, loops, for-loop, nonlinear-functions

Suppose I have the following two variables y and z and the variable x

```
y = 1:10
z = 1:10
```

Now I would like to create a jacobian of the following function

```
f <- function(x)  c(y[1]*x[1]+z[1]*x[2],
                    y[2]*x[1]+z[2]*x[2],
                      :   :     :    :
                    y[10]*x[1]+z[10]*x[2])
```

Then obtaining the Jacobian can be easily obtained by

```
jacobian(f, c(1,1))
```

Now suppose

```
y= 1:i.
```

When i becomes large, computing the function manually becomes a time-consuming task.

Is there a way to construct the same function for i?

I tried the following:

```
for (i in 1:10) {
  f[i] <- function(x)  c(y[i]*x[1]+z[i]*x[2])
} 

jacobian(f, c(1,1))
```

ThomasIsCoding suggests:

```
f <- function(x) tcrossprod(cbind(y, z), t(x))
```

Which works perfectly for this case.

Now suppose that the function is more complex

```
y[1]*x[1]^2+z[1]/x[2]
```

The t(x) suggested does no longer work. How do I now write a vector for x?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following way for function `f`

```
f <- function(x) tcrossprod(cbind(y, z), t(x))
```